# Train/change weights size on current session

Tags: python, tensorflow, size

I'm doing some tests with Tensor 1.6 and Python 2.7 trying to improve my final degree project.

I'm testing with this code:

```
batch_size = 50
var_pred = 1
x_pred = 1

hidden_1 = 100
hidden_2 = var_pred

with graph.as_default():
   Train_data_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(var_pred, batch_size ))
   Original_data_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(var_pred, var_pred ))

   '''
   # Read Tensor and save to int
   W_1_hidden =  tf.Variable(initial_value = hidden_1, dtype = tf.int32, trainable=True)
   with tf.Session() as sessi:
      tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
      W_1_hidden_i = sessi.run(W_1_hidden)
      sessi.close()
   '''

   W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([ batch_size, hidden_1 ], stddev = W_desv), dtype = tf.float32, validate_shape = False)
   b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape = [ hidden_1 ], stddev = b_desv), dtype = tf.float32, validate_shape = False)

   W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([ hidden_1, hidden_2 ], stddev = W_desv), dtype = tf.float32, validate_shape = False)
   b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape = [ hidden_2 ], stddev = b_desv), dtype = tf.float32, validate_shape = False)

   Capa_1 = tf.matmul(Train_data_ph, W_1) + b_1
   Capa_2 = tf.matmul(Capa_1, W_2) + b_2

   prediction = Capa_2
   loss = (0.5)*(tf.norm(prediction-Original_data_ph))**2

   global_step_lr = tf.Variable(0, dtype = tf.float32)
   learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_learning_rate, global_step_lr, stair_steps_learning_rate, multiply_learning_rate, staircase=True)
   optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
   gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
   def ClipIfNotNone(grad):
      if grad is None:
      return grad
      return tf.clip_by_value(grad, min_gradient, max_gradient)

   clipped_gradients = [(ClipIfNotNone(grad), var) for grad, var in gradients]
   train = optimizer.apply_gradients(clipped_gradients, global_step=global_step_lr)
```

And:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
   tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
   actual_loss = 0  
   for epoch in range(num_epochs):

      batch_data = np.zeros((var_pred, batch_size))
      original_data = np.zeros((var_pred, var_pred))

      for step in tqdm(range(num_steps)):
      #for step in tqdm(np.random.permutation(num_steps_b)):
          try:
              offset = (step*batch_size) % (total_len - batch_size)

              batch_data[0, :] = sin[offset:offset+batch_size]
              original_data[0,0] = sin_o[offset+batch_size+x_pred]

              feed_dict = {Train_data_ph : batch_data, Original_data_ph : original_data}
              _,loss_train, W_1_ = sess.run([train, loss, W_1], feed_dict = feed_dict)

              if(loss_train>0):
                  hidden_1 += 10
              actual_loss = loss_train

              time.sleep(0.0001)
```

I would like to change the Weights matrix sizes on every loop. A couple of things:

1. I have tried to do it manually, but every Variable is used like a prefixed model, so it can not be updated or changed (atleast I did not found any method).
2. After that, I tried to make a model with traineable sizes, but the Variable that contains the shape does not train and appears the same problem as before [1)]

Is it possible to train the sizes of a variable? Or change its size every loop?